# Gigabyte 2070 super loud sound

Tags: gpu, fan

I recently bought my first gaming desktop (i used to use laptop), my **GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER WINDFORCE OC 3X 8 Go** fans are very loud.

In idle or little game like League of Legends, there is absolutely no sound.
When I start any game where the gpu will really work, like Overwatch (1440p High @ 144) the fans are running all the way and the sound is very, very, very loud.

My case is **Bitfenix Dawn TG**, there are 5 fans + 3 on the GPU. 2 front, 2 top (wc Enermax 240) and one back (they come with the box).

I absolutely changed any setting in Bios or with Software, just tryed "Silence Mode" within Dragon Center (**MSI MPG X570 Gaming Edge Wifi**) and but it change nothing at all.

Edit: GPU temp is anytime at ~50°

Comment: I suggest you ask a question.

Comment: Fans spin, fans make noise. Fans spin faster and work harder, they make more noise. Adjusting control settings is potentially helpful if applicable and temps are within threshold, otherwise; consider a temporary lubrication to the fan bearings to lessen the friction and potentially help with the noise. Otherwise a new fan may help by replacing one that's defective or wore down and/or missing bearings.